# Generate Unique Pairs From Two Lists Without Itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looping over a list twice and want to catch all unique pairs, rather than all combinations- ie. order in the pair doesn't matter

```
listy=[0,1,2]
out=[]
for i in listy:
   for j in listy:
      out.append([i,j])
```

The output I'm getting is [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]

What I am looking for is [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]

One possible solution is,

```
listy=[0,1,2]
out=[]
for i in listy:
   for j in listy:
      pair=set([i,j])
      if pair not in out:
          out.append(pair)
```

This produces [{0},{0,1},{0,2},{1},{1,2},{2}]

However this creates inefficiency in what is a heavy script (the lists are long) and I also do not want a list of sets. I want a list of lists.

Is there a better way to achieve this without using itertools (I want an implementation I can also apply to javascript without too much rethinking)

Comment: The [docs for `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) lists out source code for each function in the module. Most of it is only ten or fifteen lines or so. So if you have a solution that *does* use `itertools`, then it should be relatively easy to convert it into one that doesn't.

Comment: "Is there a better way to achieve this without using itertools" Why don't you want to use `itertools`? What do you think would make for a "better" way - what standards are you using?

Comment: I misread the desired output. what you are looking for are *combinations with replacement*. You can get these for pair outputs by simply adding a check that `i <= j` (if the values are more complex, you will want to care about the *indices* rather than values) - the `i < j` cases give you the combinations without replacement, and the `i == j` cases are the extra ones that become possible with replacement. This does not easily generalize for larger outputs, because you need to nest more loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know javascript at all, but if there is something analogous to list comprehension I would try this:

```
listy = [0,1,2]
pairs = [[i, j] for i in listy for j in listy if i <= j]
```

The content of pairs is exactly as you wanted:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it doesn't eliminate duplicate pairs where both values are equal. For example, try the input `[2, 0, 1, 2]`...

Comment: You're right, if it's an option I guess I would've used list(set(pairs)) and if it's important that the elements will be lists we can recreate the list.
For sure it's getting less efficient like that :)

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 - "minor fix"

A trivial "fix" would be:

```
listy=[0,1,2]
out=set()
for i in listy:
    for j in listy:
        if (i, j) not in out and (j, i) not in out:
            out.add((i,j))
```

The result is:

```
{(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (2, 2)}
```

However this is **not** an efficient implementation, because we have to check twice if an element is in the list.

## Option 2 - More efficient implementation

You could achieve your goal using a trivial scan of the array:

```
listy=[0,1,2]
out = [(i, j) for i in range(len(listy)) for j in range(i, len(listy))]
```

NOTE: I use tuples for the pairs, you could easily change that into a list of lists using:

```
out = [[i, j] for i in range(len(listy)) for j in range(i, len(listy))]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward translation of `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(listy, 2)` (which matches the behavior you desire) that directly generates the results you want from an input `list` is:

```
listy = [0,1,2]
out = []
for idx, i in enumerate(listy):
   for j in listy[idx:]:
      out.append([i, j])
```

Only change is the use of `enumerate` (to get the current index being iterated as you iterate) and slicing the `listy` used in the inner loop (so it starts at the same index as the current run of the outer loop).

This gets the exact result requested with minimal overhead (it does make shallow copies of the `list`, of decreasing size, once for each inner loop, but this is fairly quick in Python; unless the `list` is huge, it should be a pretty minimal cost). If you need to avoid slicing, you can make the inner loop an index-based loop with indexing (but in practice, the overhead of indexing is high enough that it'll often lose to the slicing):

```
listy = [0,1,2]
out = []
for idx, i in enumerate(listy):
   for idxj in range(idx, len(listy)):
      out.append([i, j[idxj]])
```